Body of the Post request is not getting encoded in OkHttp
I've created a function to perform login functionality using OkHttp Post request. But when I try to encode my credentials and pass them in body, I get the 401 response (wrong credentials). I know that they are right, and the server is okay as well (tested with Postman), so I expect the problem to be in OkHttp or my setup of it's functionality
Here is my function:
suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): String {
        val res = withContext<String>(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor())
                .build()


            val headers = Headers.Builder()
                .add("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build()

            val body = "{\"username\":\"correct_username\",\"password\":\"correct_password\"}"
                .toRequestBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())

            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("correct_url") // Replace with your API endpoint
                .headers(headers)
                .post(
                    body
                )
                .build()

            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            

            if (response.body != null) {
                val authResponse =
                    Gson().fromJson(response.body!!.string(), AuthResponse::class.java)

                "login"
            } else {
                "no login";
            }

        }

        return res
    }

(Everything I did here is according to the documentation of OkHttp, but when I make the request with the right username and password to my api route - I expect to get the access and refresh tokens (the usual stuff), instead I get the 401 error (wrong credentials, something like that).
Now, I know that the credentials Im encoding are right, which leads me to believe that there may be a problem with OkHttp itself or with my setup of it's functions.
Another useful piece of information about my problem is that I've added a Interceptor to my OkHttp client to log requests and responses, and it says for me that the body of the request is:

